# If Condition is same then how to update multiple query in php

Tags: php, mysql

i want to update multiple query when the condition is same. it work's only for one query and remaining query is skipped without updating. can any one tell me that how it work?
 the php code is:

```
<?php
include("Database/connection.php");

$sql = "SELECT *  FROM registration,billing_month";
$result = $link->query($sql); 

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
    {
        $regid = $row['Reg_id'];
        $billid = $row['Bill_id'];
        $issuedate = $row['Bill_issue_date'];
        $duedate = $row['Bill_due_date'];
        $currentdues = $row['Current_Dues'];
        $currentbill = $row['Current_Bill'];
        $arrears = $row['Arrears'];
        $surcharge = $row['Surcharge'];
        $currentsurcharge = $row['Current_Surcharge'];

        $updatesurcharge = $currentsurcharge + $surcharge;
        $updatedsurcharge = 0;
        $updatebill = $currentbill + $currentdues;
        $updatecurrentbill = 0;
        $updatearrears = $arrears + $currentbill;
        $updatedarrears = $arrears + $currentsurcharge;
        $updatearrearsfrombill = 0;
        $updatearrearsfromsurcharge = 0;
        $addsurchargewitharrears = $arrears + $currentsurcharge;

if (strtotime(date('Y-m-d')) >= strtotime($issuedate)) 
{

  $sql_update = "UPDATE  `registration` SET `Current_Bill`= $updatebill WHERE `Reg_id` = $regid";

$sql_update = "UPDATE  `billing_month` SET `Current_Dues`= $updatecurrentbill WHERE `Bill_id` = $billid";

$sql_update = "UPDATE  `registration` SET `Current_Surcharge`= $updatesurcharge WHERE `Reg_id` = $regid";

$sql_update = "UPDATE  `billing_month` SET `Surcharge`= $updatedsurcharge WHERE `Bill_id` = $billid";

  mysqli_query($link, $sql_update);
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Basic bug. You are overwriting the `$sql_update` 4 times, so last assignment will survive and hence only last query getting executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `;` at end of every `Query Statement` then concatenate `variables`

Example

```
$sql_update = "UPDATE  `registration` SET `Current_Bill`= $updatebill WHERE `Reg_id` = $regid;";
$sql_update .= "UPDATE  `billing_month` SET `Current_Dues`= $updatecurrentbill WHERE `Bill_id` = $billid;";
$sql_update .= "UPDATE  `registration` SET `Current_Surcharge`= $updatesurcharge WHERE `Reg_id` = $regid;";
$sql_update .= "UPDATE  `billing_month` SET `Surcharge`= $updatedsurcharge WHERE `Bill_id` = $billid;";

    mysqli_query($link, $sql_update);
```

> Alternatively

You can rename you variables like `$sql_update1`, `$sql_update2` etc. and call them one by one.

Example: -

```
$sql_update1 = "UPDATE  `registration` SET `Current_Bill`= $updatebill WHERE `Reg_id` = $regid";
$sql_update2 = "UPDATE  `billing_month` SET `Current_Dues`= $updatecurrentbill WHERE `Bill_id` = $billid";
$sql_update3 = "UPDATE  `registration` SET `Current_Surcharge`= $updatesurcharge WHERE `Reg_id` = $regid";
$sql_update4 = "UPDATE  `billing_month` SET `Surcharge`= $updatedsurcharge WHERE `Bill_id` = $billid";

    mysqli_query($link, $sql_update1);
    mysqli_query($link, $sql_update2);
    mysqli_query($link, $sql_update3);
    mysqli_query($link, $sql_update4);
```

Comment: I got a quickie, When we concatenate won't it increase the execution time?

Comment: @HawasKaPujaari Yes, it will take little bit more time but defiantly take less time from my alternative solution.

Comment: Sigh* I thought you would prove me wrong. Khair, So there isn't a way for a faster executing but the multiple query executions.

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting the `sql_update` variable over and over again, hence only executing the last query.

This will do want you wanted to do (execute the query after each time you assigned it a new query) :

```
if (strtotime(date('Y-m-d')) >= strtotime($issuedate)) 
{

  $sql_update = "UPDATE  `registration` SET `Current_Bill`= $updatebill WHERE `Reg_id` = $regid";

  mysqli_query($link, $sql_update);

  $sql_update = "UPDATE  `billing_month` SET `Current_Dues`= $updatecurrentbill WHERE `Bill_id` = $billid";

  mysqli_query($link, $sql_update);    

  $sql_update = "UPDATE  `registration` SET `Current_Surcharge`= $updatesurcharge WHERE `Reg_id` = $regid";

  mysqli_query($link, $sql_update);

  $sql_update = "UPDATE  `billing_month` SET `Surcharge`= $updatedsurcharge WHERE `Bill_id` = $billid";

  mysqli_query($link, $sql_update);
}
```

Comment: is there any way to come out from this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use

```
if (strtotime(date('Y-m-d')) >= strtotime($issuedate)) 
{

  $sql_update1 = "UPDATE  `registration` SET `Current_Bill`= $updatebill WHERE `Reg_id` = $regid";

$sql_update2 = "UPDATE  `billing_month` SET `Current_Dues`= $updatecurrentbill WHERE `Bill_id` = $billid";

$sql_update3 = "UPDATE  `registration` SET `Current_Surcharge`= $updatesurcharge WHERE `Reg_id` = $regid";

$sql_update4 = "UPDATE  `billing_month` SET `Surcharge`= $updatedsurcharge WHERE `Bill_id` = $billid";

  mysqli_query($link, $sql_update1);
  mysqli_query($link, $sql_update2);
  mysqli_query($link, $sql_update3);
  mysqli_query($link, $sql_update4);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mysqli_query($link, $sql_update);
```

there is execuded Your query, and you overwrite $sql_update variable. Execute each query like that:

```
  $sql_update = "UPDATE  `registration` SET `Current_Bill`= $updatebill WHERE `Reg_id` = $regid";
  mysqli_query($link, $sql_update);
$sql_update = "UPDATE  `billing_month` SET `Current_Dues`= $updatecurrentbill WHERE `Bill_id` = $billid";
  mysqli_query($link, $sql_update);
$sql_update = "UPDATE  `registration` SET `Current_Surcharge`= $updatesurcharge WHERE `Reg_id` = $regid";
  mysqli_query($link, $sql_update);
$sql_update = "UPDATE  `billing_month` SET `Surcharge`= $updatedsurcharge WHERE `Bill_id` = $billid";

  mysqli_query($link, $sql_update);
```

Answer (score 1):

Give each query a different name and then `execute` everyone of them.

```
    if (strtotime(date('Y-m-d')) >= strtotime($issuedate)) 
    {        
      $sql_upd = "UPDATE  `registration` SET `Current_Bill`= $updatebill WHERE `Reg_id` = $regid";
      $sql_upd2 = "UPDATE  `billing_month` SET `Current_Dues`= $updatecurrentbill WHERE `Bill_id` = $billid";
      $sql_upd3 = "UPDATE  `registration` SET `Current_Surcharge`= $updatesurcharge WHERE `Reg_id` = $regid";
      $sql_upd4 = "UPDATE  `billing_month` SET `Surcharge`= $updatedsurcharge WHERE `Bill_id` = $billid";

      mysqli_query($link, $sql_upd);
      mysqli_query($link, $sql_upd2);
      mysqli_query($link, $sql_upd3);
      mysqli_query($link, $sql_upd4);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Please refer the following link:

[mysqli_multi_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php)

Comment: Please provide an answer with text and a few examples, as links cant be trusted and could end up broken at one time.

Answer (score 0):

you can execute query multiple times

```
$sql_update1 = "UPDATE  `registration` SET `Current_Bill`= $updatebill WHERE `Reg_id` = $regid";

$sql_update2 = "UPDATE  `billing_month` SET `Current_Dues`= $updatecurrentbill WHERE `Bill_id` = $billid";

$sql_update3 = "UPDATE  `registration` SET `Current_Surcharge`= $updatesurcharge WHERE `Reg_id` = $regid";

$sql_update4 = "UPDATE  `billing_month` SET `Surcharge`= $updatedsurcharge WHERE `Bill_id` = $billid";

mysqli_query($link, $sql_update1);
mysqli_query($link, $sql_update2);
mysqli_query($link, $sql_update3);
mysqli_query($link, $sql_update4);
```